# uml exercise Texas'Hold'Em Poker

Tags: uml

I'm really a beginner in dealing in Java, suprise, and we have have to make an UML class chart for a situation. I'm totally unsure about my UML-diagram and I wanted to ask, if someone with a little bit more expierience could take a look. Thank you.

This is the situation:

For poker in the Texas Hold'em variant following information is given:

For a **pokergame** you need between two and twelve **players** and a **card deck**, that has 52 **cards**. Each card has a label (e.g., "King"), a value (2 to 14) and a color (e.g., Cross). Further specified for a poker game are the sum of all inserts (the pot, e.g., 450), and five (common) cards from the deck.
For each player the name, the credit (e.g., 7592) and the current **hand**, two cards from the card deck and a value (e.g., "Full House?").

For each player it is also noted whether he has the dealer position or not.

Task: Design an UML class chart for the game without functionalities (the classes to be used are indicated by bold). For the classes, type the necessary instance variables, including their (Java-compliant) data types. Draw all the relationships between the classes. Pay attention to the information given above multiplicities.

This is my solution:

[image: And this is my solution:]

What is meant by functionalities? Did I do the relations right? Do I need methods?

Comment: You use the wrong connectors for the associations. Functionalities likely means operations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it because the classes themselves are attributes of other classes? The hand is an attribute of player. So I have an aggregation? Player and cardgame can exist without the pokergame, so I have no composition But the hand can't exist without the player and the card without the carddeck, so here it's a composition?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get the information from the text into a diagram:

[image]

You could replace the enumerations by plain attributes of type 'String'. I didn't fill out all values of HandValue (the three dots are not valid UML).
It is not clear to me whether a hand always has a value. If it has, then replace multiplicity 0..1 by 1.

If I understand the text correctly, a hand has only two cards, but this seems odd to me, I think it should be five.

You could add a composition diamond on the association between CardDeck and Card, but it is not clear from the text whether this is appropriate.

You could add a constraint, that the commonCards of a PokerGame should be a subset of the cards of the cardDeck of the PokerGame; also, that the cards of the hand of each of the players of the PokerGame are a subset of the cards of the cardDeck of the PokerGame.

You could draw an open arrowhead at the end of each association (not a triangle arrowhead; this would mean generalization), i.e. at the side where I have mentioned the multiplicity and the instance variable name.

You could specify multiplicities at the other ends of the associations, but these multiplicities are not mentioned in the text.

I didn't specify any visibilities (public/private/protected), because these are not specified in the text either.

Comment: This model is pretty close, but there are some false claims. Examples: a `Card` doesn't always have a label of Ace, King, Queen, or Jack (e.g., a 3 of clubs); a `Card Deck` does not contain 52 `Cards` once `Cards` are dealt (should be 0..52); A `Player` has no `Hand` before `Cards` are dealt.

Comment: Thank you, this really makes sense for me now. Had another exercise and I have a good feeling with it.

Comment: @JimL., thanks for your comments, I have improved the diagram. Although the text says 'each card has a label and a value', I think you are right that it's always only one or the other. You may also be right that a Card Deck has 0..52 Cards, but this is not clear from the text. I interpret 'Card Deck' as the full set of cards, even once they are dealt.

Answer (score 1):

You should not so much care about aggregation. This does not add much value to a design (but only in rare cases). Firstly your arrows are wrong. They represent generalization in UML. You need simple associations. Just leave away the arrows (which need to be unfilled open triangles) except you want to express navigability to be just in one direction (which in most cases is also nothing you need absolutely). What you should do is to use roles at the ends of the associations rather then putting typed properties in the classes. Further you should follow conventions that say class names start with an upper case letter (though I'm not really familiar with Java).

[image]

The above is a partial model to show what I mean. Note that I have added a `dealer` association. This assures that there is exactly one dealer in the game. The `{subsets players}` constraint tells that the dealer must be one of the `players` (thanks to JimL. for the hint). Using just the flag could lead to multiple dealers with the flag set. There should be a constraint that tells `isDealer` is true only for the one that is linked with the `dealer` association.

Comment: This model looks pretty accurate. On `dealer` I would add `{subsets players}` to make it clear that there cannot be 13 players.

Comment: @JimL. As said: I don't know the poker rules and whether the dealer is one of the players or some independent person :-)

Comment: From the question: "For each player it is also noted whether he has the dealer position or not."